# What does this cryptic C code snippet do?

Tags: c

I’m reading some C code that can be found at https://home.hccnet.nl/h.g.muller/umax4_8.c.
There, in `main()`, it has the following:

```
N=-1;W(++N<121)
    printf("%c",N&8&&(N+=7)?10:".?+nkbrq?*?NKBRQ"[b[N]&15]);
```

I don’t understand what this `printf()` call is doing, but somehow it outputs a chess board to the terminal.

Any idea?

Comment: this is nice obfuscated code, lol.

Comment: You're missing quite a bit here. W for example had been defined as `while`. You may want to include all pertinent code.

Comment: "...although you might describe it as obfuscated C code, due to its small size it might be easier to understand than bigger, better styled engines." H.G. Muller

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Basically, this:

```
for (n = 0; n < 121; ++n) {
    if (n & 8) {
        n += 7;
        putchar('\n');
    } else {
        putchar(".?+nkbrq?*?NKBRQ"[b[n] & 15]);
    }
}
```

What that does is, after every 8 board items, print a newline; otherwise, print out the board item indicated by `b[n]`.

Comment: H.G. Muller is C J-Y's other name ;)

Comment: @William: Funny. :-) Actually, I've done reverse engineering for many years; this is pretty much like RE, only easier because I'm not dealing directly with object code. :-P

Comment: Shouldn't `n += 7` be part of `if` condition?

Comment: @codaddict: Semantically, it's no different: `n` monotonically increases, and stops after 120, hence, will never overflow back to 0. i.e., `n += 7` is never going to be false, for the purposes of this code.